# Cannot reach datas details with map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, graphql-js, map-function

```
function Clothes() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_CLOTHES);
  const [products,setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [index,setIndex] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setProducts(data.AllItem);
      console.log(data.AllItem)
    }
      },[data,products]);

 
/*
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!loading && data){
        setProducts(data);
    }
  }, [loading, data])
*/
if (loading) return 'Loading...'               
if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`


  return (
   <section className='section'>
     <div className='title'>
       <h2>
       </h2>
       {
         products?.map((product,index) => {
           //const {gallery} = product;
           return <img src = {product.gallery} />
         })
       }
     
     </div>
   </section>
  )
}

export default Clothes;
```

> 

> [image: graphql schema]

Hello everyone I have a issues with map function. I am getting data from my graphql but when I was trying to fetch them in my console.log I can see just undefined.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try settings the data directly to the products state (remove the array) like ths:

```
const [products,setProducts] = useState(data);
```

Comment: thank you for answering but it's giving me this error ` React Hook "useQuery" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`

Comment: I have reworked my answer, maybe the issue is in the way you initially set the products state? Can you check the above variant and let me know if it works? Do you have the data correctly logged before you get this error? You can also make sure you have the products before mapping them like this:   products && products.map

Comment: Also is the data that you receive the same structure that you expect, can you share the logged data as well?

Comment: first is coming undefined and after I can see arrays.I can upload image

Answer (score 0):

few pointer the may help

```
 transform the reponse and filter the items as needed

  const { loading, error, data = [] } = useQuery(GET_CLOTHES);
  const [products,setProducts] = useState(data);
  const [index,setIndex] = useState(0)

  const transformedResponse = useMemo(() => {
    try {
    // put checks and use try catch to handle errors
    const productsList = [];

    // check for null data
    const items = data ?? []

    for (const category of items) {
      const products = category?.products ?? [];
      productsList.push(...products)
    }

    return productsList
   } catch(error) {
      // log error 
      return []
   }
  }, [data)]

  return (
     ...
     {
       transformedResponse.map(prod => {

          return (<Prod key={prod.id} {...prod} />)
       }
     }
  )
```

Docs on [working with arrays](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state)

Hope it helps

Comment: well, its not  I am still getting error but I'll check to documentations now.Thank you, again.

Comment: Welcome, I put few more check, putting try catch could help with find the problem, you can try to share the response and logs so that we can help

Comment: Sure, when I try this function error is map is not a function. I can upload image if it will be more efficent